# How to create openlayer map in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, openlayers

I want to know that can we create Open Layer map application without using JavaScript API means phone gap. I want to create this Open Layer application with use of X Code native codes and Map. Is it possible to create Open Layer application without using Phone Gap??
Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Phonegap you can create a simple iPhone application with UIWebView and use OpenLayers inside of it. [Here's how you do this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64420/how-can-i-write-an-iphone-app-entirely-in-javascript-without-making-it-just-a-web)

Comment: do you have any idea about making such kind of application? or sample code for creating such kind of application.? Right now i am looking into your given link & trying to implement like that way. thanks for help. please reply if you have any idea about that.