# New to developing iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode

As someone who has never developed an iOS app but hopes to soon and has never had a Mac (to date) the whole XCode and process for developing apps was a little lost on me.

To start: things like which languages are supported in development was one area I wasn't sure of:

I've seen C, C++ and Objective-C referenced as the languages used to write the apps. But I've also seen JavaScript` + HTML + CSS and .NET as options and a host of other compiled languages, with people arguing if you can or can't use them.

Another thing I wondered about was Xcode, does it support all the mentioned languages?  Or is an IDE built for a specific language such as Cocoa ? If it is, then how would someone use JavaScript for example to write the app?

I'm sure this is a fairly simple answer to Apple users, but I had some struggle trying to relate from a non-Apple background.

**Updated**
Thanks for the great answers and insight, hopefully other this post will be helpful to others who don't have an Apple / iOS background

Comment: It definitely supports Objective-C, C, and C++ (Objective-C++).  I have never heard of it in conjunction with JavaScript, HTML, etc.

Comment: There's quite a lot of information available on the web that's accessible to new developers who "don't have an Apple/iOS background." I'd recommend starting with Apple's introductory document: [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three language alternatives that you mentioned are available to iOS application developers <sup>*</sup>.

Objective-C/C++ offers a way of making native apps for iOS, you produce machine code that runs on the devices. You use Xcode to develop in these languages.

You can build apps in JavaScript + HTML + CSS because iOS comes with a browser. Apple offers a mode that gives your apps a completely native look and feel, so they do look like first-class citizens.

You can build your apps in C# as well by using Mono Touch. This is different from .NET, although the language is the same, because your code is compiled into binary ahead of time. Although using Mono Touch eliminates the learning curve associated with the new language, you need to go through a fair bit of learning to adapt your knowledge of .NET to a different platform.

<sup>*</sup> Except Cocoa, which is not a language, but a collective name for Apple's frameworks for developing under OS X and iOS.

Comment: Thanks, interesting what you mention about JavaScript. I'd rather try and write in that, than learn a whole new language, but i'm not opposed to this approach either. Would there be any downsides with using JavaScript as a base?

Comment: @Jonnny The answer depends a lot on the kind of the app that you are considering. Unless your app needs to do heavy computations (e.g. a game engine) or hold/process significant amounts of data, it would do perfectly fine in JavaScript. If you plan to develop a game that is heavy on the graphics, you would be better off with Objective-C/C++.

Comment: No, it would be your typical kind of view, push notifications on different kinds of events. Nothing heavy. My final question, what IDE would you attempt to develop a JavaScript based iOS in and is JQuery an option?

Comment: @Jonnny Although you do not need a specific IDE to develop for iOS in JavaScript+HTML+CSS, a number of alternatives is available. You could build and test [using Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/64763/335858), or use [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/titanium-studio/) for some cross-platform capabilities. You could also use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), which lets you build for several platforms from the same source.

Answer (score 3):

iOS' native language is Objective-C. While it's true you can use C++ to make apps (Cocos for example, is mostly written in C++) it isn't the 'native language'.

As for the other languages you mention, while it's possible to create apps using them they won't be 'native' normally relying upon another IDE/Library, phone gap or adobe air for example. Most of these also support cross platform development.

Where I work we also use HTML5 to create a 'faux native' interface/experience.

If you're new to iOS it's worth while checking out Apple documentation/sample code at:

https://developer.apple.com

There is a wealth of knowledge there that should set you on the right path. It ins't however, something I'd recommend if you don't have any experience with object orientated programming.

Coming from a C++ background myself, I didn't find it too difficult but have been working on iOS for about 3 years (on and off) and am only just starting to really become truly fluent in it's processes and conventions.

Hope this helps, let me know if you want to know anything specific.

Comment: +1 But PhoneGap is a library, not an IDE.

Comment: Cocos(2d), not to be confused with Cocoa.

Comment: @CW0007007 Thanks for that insight, it was helpful to me.